# SunPkcs11: CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED

Tags: java, sign

I'm trying to get certs from a smart card but when initialize the Sun PKCS11 provider I get the following error:

```
java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:374)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:107)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_TOKEN_NOT_RECOGNIZED
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetTokenInfo(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.Token.<init>(Token.java:130)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.initToken(SunPKCS11.java:804)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:365)
    ... 44 more
```

My code:

```
String providerConfig = "name=PKCS11\r\nlibrary=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\UsrPkcs11.dll\r\n";
ByteArrayInputStream providerConfigBAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(providerConfig.getBytes());
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 provider = new SunPKCS11(providerConfigBAIS);
```

¿Any idea with this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a guess but... Are you sure your system32 contains UsrPkcs11.dll? For example, I'm using eTPKCS11.dll (system32/eTPKCS11.dll) for my token. And what Token are you using?

Comment: I have the dll in my system32 path, anyway before instantiate the provider, I check the dll with File.exist().